# Deserialize XML to C# class error with unexpected type (2,2)

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Goal is to deserialize a XML file into a c# object.
I've used [this](https://jsonformatter.org/xml-to-csharp) site to create the object class.

When I try to read a XML file, I get an error:

*The XML-document (2,2) contains an error.
Didn't expect <PXML_Document xmlns="http://progress-m.com/ProgressXML/Version1">*

Obviously something is missing/wrong with the partial class, but I'm too new to figure it out.
Can someone help me please?

Example header XML

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>       
> <PXML_Document xmlns="http://progress-m.com/ProgressXML/Version1">
> <DocInfo GlobalID="7C7E1FC5-0A46-48c5-A3B2-249D75B70BCF">
> <MajorVersion>1</MajorVersion>
> <MinorVersion>3</MinorVersion>
> </DocInfo>
> <Order>
> <OrderNo>SF20-0178-BO</OrderNo>
> <Storey>&lt;Storey /&gt;</Storey>
> <DrawingDate>24/09/2020</DrawingDate>
> ```

C# class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

namespace Unitechnik_PXML_
{
public partial class Welcome2
{
    [JsonProperty("PXML_Document")]
    public PxmlDocument PxmlDocument { get; set; }
}

public partial class PxmlDocument
{
    [JsonProperty("DocInfo")]
    public DocInfo DocInfo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Order")]
    public Order Order { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("_xmlns")]
    public Uri Xmlns { get; set; }
}

public partial class DocInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("MajorVersion")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PurpleParseStringConverter))]
    public long MajorVersion { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("MinorVersion")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PurpleParseStringConverter))]
    public long MinorVersion { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("_GlobalID")]
    public string GlobalId { get; set; }
}

public partial class Order
{
    [JsonProperty("OrderNo")]
    public string OrderNo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Storey")]
    public string Storey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DrawingDate")]
    public string DrawingDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DrawingRevision")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PurpleParseStringConverter))]
    public long DrawingRevision { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ApplicationName")]
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ApplicationVersion")]
    public string ApplicationVersion { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrderArea")]
    public string OrderArea { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Product")]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}

public partial class Product
{
    [JsonProperty("ElementNo")]
    public string ElementNo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ProductType")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PurpleParseStringConverter))]
    public long ProductType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TotalThickness")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PurpleParseStringConverter))]
    public long TotalThickness { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DoubleWallsGap")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PurpleParseStringConverter))]
    public long DoubleWallsGap { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("PieceCount")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PurpleParseStringConverter))]
    public long PieceCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TurnWidth")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PurpleParseStringConverter))]
    public long TurnWidth { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TurnMoveX")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PurpleParseStringConverter))]
    public long TurnMoveX { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("RotationPosition")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PurpleParseStringConverter))]
    public long RotationPosition { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("P1X")]
    public string P1X { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("P1Y")]
    public string P1Y { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("P1Z")]
    public string P1Z { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("P2X")]
    public string P2X { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("P2Y")]
    public string P2Y { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("P2Z")]
    public string P2Z { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("P3X")]
    public string P3X { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("P3Y")]
    public string P3Y { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("P3Z")]
    public string P3Z { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ItemPosition")]
    public string ItemPosition { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ElementInfo")]
    public string ElementInfo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Slab")]
    public Slab Slab { get; set; }
}

public partial class Slab
{
    [JsonProperty("SlabNo")]
    public string SlabNo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("SlabArea")]
    public string SlabArea { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("SlabWeight")]
    public string SlabWeight { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ProductionThickness")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PurpleParseStringConverter))]
    public long ProductionThickness { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("MaxLength")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PurpleParseStringConverter))]
    public long MaxLength { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("MaxWidth")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PurpleParseStringConverter))]
    public long MaxWidth { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ProjectCoordinates")]
    public string ProjectCoordinates { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("GenericInfo01")]
    public string GenericInfo01 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("GenericInfo02")]
    public string GenericInfo02 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("GenericInfo03")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PurpleParseStringConverter))]
    public long GenericInfo03 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Outline")]
    public Outline[] Outline { get; set; }
}

public partial class Outline
{
    [JsonProperty("Z")]
    public string Z { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Height")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PurpleParseStringConverter))]
    public long Height { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ConcreteQuality", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string ConcreteQuality { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("UnitWeight")]
    public string UnitWeight { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Volume")]
    public string Volume { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Layer", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PurpleParseStringConverter))]
    public long? Layer { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Shape")]
    public ShapeUnion Shape { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("_Type")]
    public TypeEnum Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("X", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PurpleParseStringConverter))]
    public long? X { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Y", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PurpleParseStringConverter))]
    public long? Y { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("GenericInfo02", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string GenericInfo02 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("MountPartDirection", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PurpleParseStringConverter))]
    public long? MountPartDirection { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("MountPartType", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string MountPartType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("MountPartLength", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PurpleParseStringConverter))]
    public long? MountPartLength { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("MountPartWidth", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PurpleParseStringConverter))]
    public long? MountPartWidth { get; set; }
}

public partial class ShapeElement
{
    [JsonProperty("SVertex")]
    public SVertex[] SVertex { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Cutout", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(FluffyParseStringConverter))]
    public bool? Cutout { get; set; }
}

public partial class SVertex
{
    [JsonProperty("X")]
    public string X { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Y")]
    public string Y { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Bulge")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PurpleParseStringConverter))]
    public long Bulge { get; set; }
}

public partial class PurpleShape
{
    [JsonProperty("SVertex")]
    public SVertex[] SVertex { get; set; }
}

public enum TypeEnum { Lot, Mountpart };

public partial struct ShapeUnion
{
    public PurpleShape PurpleShape;
    public ShapeElement[] ShapeElementArray;

    public static implicit operator ShapeUnion(PurpleShape PurpleShape) => new ShapeUnion { PurpleShape = PurpleShape };
    public static implicit operator ShapeUnion(ShapeElement[] ShapeElementArray) => new ShapeUnion { ShapeElementArray = ShapeElementArray };
}

public partial class Welcome2
{
    public static Welcome2 FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Welcome2>(json, Unitechnik_PXML_.Converter.Settings);
}

public static class Serialize
{
    public static string ToJson(this Welcome2 self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, Unitechnik_PXML_.Converter.Settings);
}

internal static class Converter
{
    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        Converters =
        {
            ShapeUnionConverter.Singleton,
            TypeEnumConverter.Singleton,
            new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
        },
    };
}

internal class PurpleParseStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(long) || t == typeof(long?);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
        var value = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
        long l;
        if (Int64.TryParse(value, out l))
        {
            return l;
        }
        throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type long");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (untypedValue == null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
            return;
        }
        var value = (long)untypedValue;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value.ToString());
        return;
    }

    public static readonly PurpleParseStringConverter Singleton = new PurpleParseStringConverter();
}

internal class ShapeUnionConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(ShapeUnion) || t == typeof(ShapeUnion?);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.StartObject:
                var objectValue = serializer.Deserialize<PurpleShape>(reader);
                return new ShapeUnion { PurpleShape = objectValue };
            case JsonToken.StartArray:
                var arrayValue = serializer.Deserialize<ShapeElement[]>(reader);
                return new ShapeUnion { ShapeElementArray = arrayValue };
        }
        throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type ShapeUnion");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var value = (ShapeUnion)untypedValue;
        if (value.ShapeElementArray != null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value.ShapeElementArray);
            return;
        }
        if (value.PurpleShape != null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value.PurpleShape);
            return;
        }
        throw new Exception("Cannot marshal type ShapeUnion");
    }

    public static readonly ShapeUnionConverter Singleton = new ShapeUnionConverter();
}

internal class FluffyParseStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(bool) || t == typeof(bool?);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
        var value = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
        bool b;
        if (Boolean.TryParse(value, out b))
        {
            return b;
        }
        throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type bool");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (untypedValue == null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
            return;
        }
        var value = (bool)untypedValue;
        var boolString = value ? "true" : "false";
        serializer.Serialize(writer, boolString);
        return;
    }

    public static readonly FluffyParseStringConverter Singleton = new FluffyParseStringConverter();
}

internal class TypeEnumConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(TypeEnum) || t == typeof(TypeEnum?);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
        var value = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
        switch (value)
        {
            case "lot":
                return TypeEnum.Lot;
            case "mountpart":
                return TypeEnum.Mountpart;
        }
        throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type TypeEnum");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (untypedValue == null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
            return;
        }
        var value = (TypeEnum)untypedValue;
        switch (value)
        {
            case TypeEnum.Lot:
                serializer.Serialize(writer, "lot");
                return;
            case TypeEnum.Mountpart:
                serializer.Serialize(writer, "mountpart");
                return;
        }
        throw new Exception("Cannot marshal type TypeEnum");
    }

    public static readonly TypeEnumConverter Singleton = new TypeEnumConverter();
}
```

}

Comment: Consider not using that site. I don't know why it proposes such convoluted JSON.NET (notice the **JSON** in JSON.NET?) code for parsing XML...

Comment: I think the issue is with the XML file, check if the format is correct, or try to use an online XML parser to see if could be parsed successfully, look carefully what tags are not closed(hint: Order and PXML_Document)

Comment: First of all: Your xml is invalid. Second: If you have Visual Studio, you can use the `paste special` command and paste xml as classes. That way you should have a valid serializable class.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you found [that site](https://jsonformatter.org/xml-to-csharp) and why anyone expects it to work. You paste XML, and you get JSON parsing code back. That's not gonna fly, JSON is not XML. When fixing your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PXML_Document xmlns="http://progress-m.com/ProgressXML/Version1">
  <DocInfo GlobalID="7C7E1FC5-0A46-48c5-A3B2-249D75B70BCF">
    <MajorVersion>1</MajorVersion>
    <MinorVersion>3</MinorVersion>
  </DocInfo>
  <Order>
    <OrderNo>SF20-0178-BO</OrderNo>
    <Storey>&lt;Storey /&gt;</Storey>
    <DrawingDate>24/09/2020</DrawingDate>
  </Order>
</PXML_Document>
```

And generating the code through that site, the code throws:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.'

So that's that. Just copy your XML, create a new file, and choose `Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML As Classes`.

Then you get a couple of classes you can use with the default XmlSerializer:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PXML_Document)).Deserialize(File.OpenRead("OrderData.xml"));
```

Comment: Thanks man!
Paste special XML as classes works like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

You have unicode characters in the file.  If you put code into notepad and then do a SaveAs and change file type to UTF-8 the unicode characters will get removed.  I used following code to test your xml and classes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PxmlDocument));
            PxmlDocument pxmlDocument = (PxmlDocument)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
 
        }

    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName =  "PXML_Document", Namespace = "http://progress-m.com/ProgressXML/Version1")]
    public partial class PxmlDocument
    {
        public DocInfo DocInfo { get; set; }

        public Order Order { get; set; }

    }

    public partial class DocInfo
    {
        public long MajorVersion { get; set; }

        public long MinorVersion { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class Order
    {
        public string OrderNo { get; set; }

        public string Storey { get; set; }

        public string DrawingDate { get; set; }

        public long DrawingRevision { get; set; }

        public string ApplicationName { get; set; }

        public string ApplicationVersion { get; set; }

        public string OrderArea { get; set; }

        //public Product Product { get; set; }
    }



}
```

Comment: "I totally changed your classes and it works for me, so the problem must be Unicode" +1